# how can i get the list of changes between two git hash remotely

Tags: git, version-control

I have two git hash i would like to get the log of all changes between them but this is happening on server I need a way to not make a local copy or it would involve a pretty involved procedure.

It was perfect when I use to do it with svn just having svn command line i could query it with a username for difference between two builds.

```
svn --username="bla" --password="bla" log http://svnrepository -r100:102
```

Can't a git repository remotely act like a server to me so I can execute this remotely?

Comment: How exactly is making a local copy a "pretty involved procedure"? Git is designed to be very very easy to clone (and anything else involving remotes). And once you have a clone, fetching updates is quick.

Comment: I can imagine SVN does nothing else, than downloading the file(s), comparing and deleting them, too.

Comment: Jefromi the problem is getting the clone when dealing with massive repositories I meant in terms of infrastructure I need to have all space requirements and other things monitored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your repository is really so huge that this would be a win over just cloning the repository, I think you can do this with a script that uses `git archive` with its `--remote` option.  You can easily alter [this script](https://gist.github.com/498628) along those lines to take a remote repository parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. A diff running on remote versions would be incredibly slow compared to doing it locally and git tries to do things locally. The best you can do is to clone the repository and then diff between the two remote branches.

OTOH, you might be able to use some kind of git web interface to see diffs online.